# How to make my code to return empty string?

Tags: c, function

Here's implementation of strstr function in C. I have problem with returning empty string.

Input: `""` and `""`

It should return not NULL:

(Nothing, just empty string)

How do I implement it?

```
#include "string.h"

char *my_strstr (char *str, char *substr)
{
    char *empty = "";
    if (str == empty && substr == empty) return empty;
    while (*str) 
    {
            char *Begin = str;
            char *pattern = substr;
        
            while (*str && *pattern && *str == *pattern) 
            {
                  str++;
                  pattern++;
            }
            // If complete sub string match, return starting address 
            if (!*pattern)
                  return Begin;
                  
            str = Begin + 1;    // Increment main string 
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You should use `strcmp`, not `==`.

Comment: The parameters to `strstr` should both be `const char *`.

Comment: `str == empty` and `substr == empty` are always false. Remember that "strings" in C are merely _pointers_ to the first character of the string. You can obviously not compare strings by comparing the pointers to them. Use `strcmp` for comparing strings; read it's documentation carefully.

Comment: You can use `strcmp`, but using it to compare with the empty string is a little bit overkill and not quite idiomatic.  I would write `if (!*substr) return str;` Note that `strstr` should return a pointer within the given string, and not a pointer to an unrelated empty string.  You can also omit the test for `str` being empty, because if `substr` is empty then you will eventually return `str` whether `str` is empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:
1) One must use `strcmp()` or implement one's own to compare strings. `==` cannot be used to compare strings, and will always return false. Example

```
char *str1="str";
char *str2="str";
if (str1==str2){
    printf("== returns true.\n");
}
if (strcmp(str1,str2)){
    printf("strcmp() returns true.\n");
}
```

Output

```
strcmp() returns true.
```

2) One must not return a pointer to a local variable. In this case, `return empty` is not okay.
3) To return an empty string, do

```
char *emptystr;
emptystr=malloc(sizeof(char));
*emptystr='\0';
return emptystr;
```

Notice that here `malloc` is used, instead of the **incorrect** version

```
char emptystr[1];
```

which causes the returning of a pointer to a local variable.

Comment: In the original code, `return empty` is okay because it's a pointer to a string literal (`""`) which has static storage duration.  Note the code was `char *empty = "";` and not `char empty[] = "";`.  But as I mention in the comment, it's not correct for `strstr` to return a pointer to an unrelated string.